# Gridview doesn't change when data changes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridview, data-binding

I've added an observable data and bound it to my data grid as follows.

```
private ObservableCollection<Order> _allOrders;
public ObservableCollection<Order> AllOrders
{
  get { return _allOrders;}
  set { _allOrders = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
}

public Presenter() { _allOrders = new ObservableCollection<Order>(...); }

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
{
  PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

When I set breakpoint on the event that is supposed to filter the data, I set the property *AllOrder* to *null*. I can verify using the watch that it's set to that. However, the view isn't updated, so I'm guessing that I forgot something. The view model class *Presenter* implements *INotifyPropertyChanged* interface, of course.

What's missing?

## Edit

The XAML code for the grid looks as follows.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding AllOrders}"
          AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_OnAutoGeneratingColumn" ...>
```

Comment: You don't need `PropertyChanged*` for an ObservableCollection. The collection already does all notification to bindings. Please show (the relevant part of) your XAML

Comment: @DrKoch I followed the patter using [by this blogger](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/11/14/filtering-data-in-your-view-model.aspx). Perhaps it's not the optimal approach. As for the XAML, which part is the relevant in this case? I've added what I **think** it is. Please view the edit.

Comment: @KonradViltersten do I understand correctly that initially you can see some items (binding works) but at some point you set `AllOrders` to null and items don't disappear? And yes you need `PropertyChanged` in `AllOrders` if you later set that property. `ObservableCollection` only covers what happens to items in collection.

Comment: @dkozl You understood correctly. And since I'm going to filter back and forth, I'd actually prefer to just show the items that have the property *Active* changed to something, rather than assigning the whole property *AllOrders* all over.

Comment: Please show us the code where you set `AllOrders` to null. The point which cause you a problem.

Comment: @KonradViltersten if you filter items I would suggest create [`ListCollectionView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview(v=vs.110).aspx) from `_allOrders`, make it a public property, bind `DataGrid` to that property instead, set [`Filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc452341(v=vs.110).aspx) and call [`Refresh`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.refresh(v=vs.110).aspx) when you want to update UI

Comment: @user2250152 That point causes me no problems. The fact that I have no update in the data grid is is the problem. I set the *AllOrder* to null in the handler for the event of a checkbox being selected.

Comment: @KonradViltersten WPF does not bind directly to a collection but to a view and you can create that view manually. In view model nothing changes. You still work on _allItems_ and changes to _ObservableCollection<T>_ are picked automatically by UI but you can filter, sort and refresh manually

Comment: @dkozl I'll gladly go with your suggestion. Post it as a reply, please. And I'll do more googling on the keywords suggested by you.

Comment: @dkozl Just to be clear on two points. **Something** does change in the view model, I need to add a new property of type *ListCollectionView*, right? But I still keep the private property *_allOrders* in my class, correct? And **that** data doesn't change. That's what you meant, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you set `DataContext` accordingly and `AllOrders` binding works initially if you want to filter items in the UI, without change collection, it's much easier when you use [`ListCollectionView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview(v=vs.110).aspx) with a [`Filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc452341(v=vs.110).aspx). WPF does not bind directly to collection but to a view - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx#binding_to_collections).

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<Order> _allOrders;

private readonly ListCollectionView _filteredOrders;

public ICollectionView FilteredOrders 
{ 
    get { return _filteredOrders; } 
}

public Presenter() 
{ 
    _allOrders = new ObservableCollection<Order>(...);
    _filteredOrders = new ListCollectionView(_allOrders); 
    _filteredOrders.Filter = o => ((Order)o).Active;
}
```

and in XAML

```
<DataGrid ... ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredOrders}">
```

when you want to manually refresh UI just call [`Refresh`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.refresh(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
_filteredOrders.Refresh();
```

Apart from that nothing changes in the view model. You still add/remove items to `_allItems` and changes should be picked up automatically by UI

Comment: Great. +½ for a flexibly alternative suggestion and +½ for nice code sample in the reply including the linkage.

Answer (score 0):

Do you set the property `AllOrders` only in the constructor? If so, then do not set the field `_allOrders` but the property `AllOrders`. If you set the field then notification is never raised.

Comment: I'm setting the private *_allOrders* in the constructor. Then, when checking the checkbox, I assign to the public *AllOrders*. The notification should be raised, then.